# Cordova plugin error

Tags: java, cordova

I am trying make cordova plugin and I stuck with JAVA code. I need to iterate json in  function and set parameters to intent extra fields
JAVA CODE

```
          Iterator keys = obj.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String dynamicKey = (String) keys.next();
                Object value = dynamicKey.get(dynamicKey);
                if (value instanceof Integer){
                    intent.putExtra(dynamicKey, dynamicKey.getInt(dynamicKey));
                } else {
                    intent.putExtra(dynamicKey, dynamicKey.getString(dynamicKey));
                }
            }
```

With compilation I receive such errors:

> cards.java:76: error: cannot find symbol intent.putExtra(dynamicKey, dynamicKey.getString(dynamicKey));
>
> cards.java:74: error: cannot find symbol intent.putExtra(dynamicKey, dynamicKey.getInt(dynamicKey));
>
> cards.java:72: error: cannot find symbol Object value = dynamicKey.get(dynamicKey);

Whats wrong?

Comment: Are you missing some imports for the missing symbols?

Comment: sorry i newbie in JAVA and its first and last expiriense of JAVA, which symbols i need import?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have errors around the types you're trying to use. You are calling `get`, `getInt` and `getString` on `dynamicKey`, which is a `String` and does not have those methods available. That's why it's throwing errors when you try to compile.

Comment: so, i just must remove String and (String) from String dynamicKey = (String) keys.next() ?